# How to make network requests in the background in an Android app?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner programmer, making a simple app that sends an HTTP request to an api and gets some information back. I want the app to keep doing this and updating automatically about every hour. I have this working successfully using HttpURLConnection, a Loader that extends AsyncTaskLoader, and a Handler and Runnable that restarts the loader at fixed amounts of time.

This works fine when the app is in the foreground, but as soon as I switch to a different app or turn the screen off, it stops working. I tried using a partial wake lock to keep the app running, but although the app is running, as soon as it stops being in the foreground, all network activity stops and I get an

W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection

warning message. Is there anything I can do to keep this connection active when the app is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Service.

**Service**

```
public class TimeService extends Service {
        // constant
        public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds

        // run on another Thread to avoid crash
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        // timer handling
        private Timer mTimer = null;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // cancel if already existed
            if(mTimer != null) {
                mTimer.cancel();
            } else {
                // recreate new
                mTimer = new Timer();
            }
            // schedule task
            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
        }

        class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run on another thread
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // display toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDateTime(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });
            }

            private String getDateTime() {
                // get date time in custom format
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss]");
                return sdf.format(new Date());
            }

        }
```

**Manifest**

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".TimeService"/>
    </application>
```

**Main class**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, TimeService.class));
    }
```

[Source](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/create-a-service-that-does-a-schedule-task/)